# Loop with rewrite rules in apache 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

With my apache 2.4 I want the following:

- `GET /file.html` -> 301 redirect to path `/~`
- `GET /~` -> return content of file `/file.html`

In my `.htaccess` I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^file.html ~ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^~ file.html [L]
```

But now also `GET /~` returns a 301 redirect to `/~`. Where is the bug? I thought, that for `GET /~` the first rule is not applied and the second rule will return the content of file `file.html`. Is this what I want possible with `mod_rewrite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your rules is that it will cause infinite looping since both rules are rewriting like this: `A->B` and `B->A`.

You can use this rule to avoid looping:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+file\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ ~ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^~$ file.html [L,B]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.